# Roblox Empty Group Finder

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local group = game:GetService("GroupService")
local id = 0
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    wait(2)
    while wait(0.01) do
        local stop = false
        id += 1
    local info = 0
        if stop == false then
            if  group:GetGroupInfoAsync(id) then
                    local info = group:GetGroupInfoAsync(id)
                    print(info)
                    if info["Owner"] then
                    local owner = info["Owner"]["Name"]
                    local id = info["Id"]
                    if owner then
                        local name = info["Name"]
                        local result = name.." (ID: "..id..") is owned by "..owner.."!"
                        print(result)
                        plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.Text = result
                    end
                elseif info["Owner"] == nil then
                    plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.Text = "Group found! ID: "..id
                    while true do
                        wait()
                        stop = true
                end
                end
            else
                id += 1
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

It works but it stops because http://roblox.com/groups/12 isn't a valid group.  I want it to pass that and add to the id.  How do I do it?
Error: **GroupService:GetGroupInfoAsync() failed because HTTP 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: Have you tried using a `pcall`? Here is a guide on the [Roblox DevForum](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/pcalls-when-and-how-to-use-them/393687) on how to use them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LUA's very handy `pcall` function to catch errors.

Here is a guide on the [Roblox DevForum](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/pcalls-when-and-how-to-use-them/393687) on how to use them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
_G.HDAdminMain:GetModule("cf"):SetRank(game:GetService("Players")["YourUserNameHere"], group.GroupId, Ownership, "Claim")
```

-- don't change anything unless you know what your doing